# Set a SQL Cursor position by DateTime

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate

I haven't seen this question asked before, and if it has, please let me know! Cursors are new to me and I'm learning. I'm asking for advice because I'm not certain that what I need to do is even possible.

We have a (C#, Nhibernate) service that collects data at 1am every day that reads from a cursor position and saves the last 24 hours of entries to a file. We store the current cursor location as we go along for the next time the service runs.

The customer feels that it's possible, but very rare, that data might be missed for certain days and they want to be able to "manually" go back to a previous 24 hour period and collect the data again. They want a GUI with a DatePicker and a "Run" button. they want to be able to get records that might be weeks old.

My question is: How do I obtain a row number to set the cursor position to (in C# Sql,or NHibernate, or EF) for a specific record based on a DateTime value?

(I know that BizTalk might perform this automated service better, but the customer wants special operations done with the data! If you know of a good way to do this in BizTalk, please advise! there's a possibility we can switch.)

I am uncertain if this is possible.

Thank you for your help and kind regards.

Comment: This is a very vague description.   Can you show us some code, and what exactly you want to change in it?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a cursor specifically and not just selecting from a range of DateTime values?  Cursors in SQL are VERY inefficient and there is generally a set-based solution that might have been unexplored.

Comment: Since cursors are new to you, forget you ever heard of them.  Search for "set based" and "sql server".  You terminology may be wrong.  You may be simply searching for a row on a certain criteria.  The best thing is to post a sample.  (Create a #temp table..insert rows into it (sample data).....and then ask for what your fishing for)

Comment: A cursor just allows you to perform task iteratively, e.g. execute a stored procedure on the results of a query.  What record it was pointing to at any given time would just be whatever iteration of the loop happened to be executing at that time.

Comment: I'm stuck with cursors at this point. There are no DateTime columns in any of the tables to select from. Does anyone know if system base tables contain a modified or insert DateTime for each row that I can use to read from? I'm researching that as a solution. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: BTW: I can't really show code because reading by date is a new feature request. The existing "old" code uses NHibernate by cursor position. That's why I'm trying to find a way to obtain the place to move the cursor to, and then run the Nhibernate read.

Comment: Without prior logging setup, there is no way to know when rows were inserted into a table.  Are you able to modify the table structure at all?  You could add an 'IsProcessed' bit field and set it to 1 at the end of the job, only selecting rows with a 0.  This solves both your problems of selecting any rows that might have been missed and gets rid of your cursor.

Comment: Thanks TTeeple, Ben, Granada, and Tab. I'm hoping that there's a hidden base table that stores a copy of the "insert" or "modified" DateTime for each row... Looking for detailed info on the web...

Comment: Long-story-short. "Cursor" is not an SQL cursor, it's a utc time ticks since "a long time ago." If someone wants to post their responses above as an answer then I'll chose it. All of them are technically correct. thanks again for your help.

Comment: There is not a hidden base table.   If you are using transactional recovery, you might be able to parse that information with a third-party log reader.   It would be a huge undertaking though.   And why are you calling this a sql cursor?   sounds like the cursor is in nhibernate to me.

Comment: I misunderstood the existing system. "Cursor" is a utc time integer since 1970. I'll probably leave this question up because others who are new to SQL cursors might try to do the same thing. The answer is approximately this: you can't set an SQL cursor to a specific datetime without knowing the data set and data having some form of a time stamp as a column.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a long conversation about the basics of SQL Server, I've determined that one cannot set an SQL cursor to a specific datetime without knowing the data set and data having some form of a time stamp as a column.